# Why does Javascript's `parseFloat` return a different value than Java's `java.lang.Double.parseDouble` when truncating over-sized numbers?

Tags: javascript, java, floating-point, rounding, precision

Javascript:

```js
> parseFloat("738529527931269425")
738529527931269400
```

Java:

```scala
@ java.lang.Double.parseDouble("738529527931269425")
res4: Double = 7.3852952793126938E17

@ (long)java.lang.Double.parseDouble("738529527931269425")
res5: Long = 738529527931269376L
```

Shouldn't they be the same? Is one of them wrong? Or are there multiple valid ways of truncating overly-precise decimal numbers to fit into 64 bit floats?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: Because Java and JavaScript are two completely different programming languages?

Comment: Is a variance of 1/100000000000000 really important to your application?

Comment: Also note that the difference may stem from the code used to render the numeric values in internal form out for printing in base 10.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Indeed, they are two completely different languages but that does not explain what's happening. I still think the question is valid: why there are two different results? Is one of them calculated wrong? Or both are valid but somehow can be different?

Comment: Java just decides to display one more significant digit (938, instead of 94), but the number is likely the same in the internal representation of matissa and exponent. But as it is binary, the conversion to decimal needs to stop somewhere. They selected a different cutoff point. 738529527931269425 is too large to exactly represent in double floating point.

Comment: You are better off in JavaScript using BigInt type, and in Java, BigInteger due to the differences in the implementation of the (display of) IEEE 754 standard 64-bit floating-point number

Comment: Basically because JavaScript interpreters and Java compilers have neither the same algorithm nor the same injunctions in numerical precision. Otherwise, the quality in digital precision being intensive in CPU time, its priority is lower over all the tasks that a computer endUser must carry out. In other words, if you need to perform high-precision calculations on client workstations, it is means your client/server task distribution is poorly done.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek It's not a valid question because it's assuming a false equivalency. Why not compare Java to C# or JavaScript to PHP or PHP to Java? Each language has it's own types and their own interpreters or compilers.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I agree, why not? It doesn't matter they are different languages. The question is not about syntax or some framework mechanics. It's about a seemingly language-agnostic operation that one could argue should give the same result no matter what language is used (just as Math). And yet the results are different. Therefore OP is asking why two languages give a different output for the same input when seemingly the same operation is used. Based on the comments above it looks like apparently it's not the same because IEEE754 can be implemented differently. But the question is valid IMO.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek *"it looks like apparently it's not the same because IEEE754 can be implemented differently"* <-- So, what does that tell you? The two languages handle  the problem differently. Therefore, the answer is "don't expect two different languages, with different interpreters/compilers/implementations to work the same."

Comment: @ScottMarcus If this is the answer - fine. But still, the question was valid. OP thought the "parseFloat operation" should be the same for all languages, just as Math operations are. But it's not - and that's fine, that's the answer. But the question is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the results are the same. The differences are in the string representations, not in the double actually stored in memory.

Doubles (in Java) and Numbers (in JavaScript) are 64-bit binary floating point numbers specified by the IEEE-754 standard. They have a precision of 53 bits, which is about 15 decimal digits. It doesn't matter whether those bits/digits are before or after the binary/decimal separator. Your number has 18 significant digits, so not all integer numbers in its neighbourhood can be exactly represented. So numbers need to be rounded to the nearest number which can be represented. And the strings "738529527931269376", "7.3852952793126938E17", "738529527931269400" and "738529527931269425" are all mapped to the exact same double value, which is the closest one to all of them. For example:

```
Double.parseDouble("7.3852952793126938E17") == Double.parseDouble("738529527931269400")
// ==> true
```

When converting a floating point value to a string, any of the many strings which would be mapped back to that floating point value may be chosen. Most programming languages don't simply output the exact value of the floating point value as a decimal string, but choose the "simplest" string among all the possible ones. "Simple", of course, is not very clearly defined, which is the reason you see different results here.